# VSCode debugger/Contributions Point/Proposed API

Tags: vscode-debugger

I am working on **enabledApiProposals** in Proposed API/VSCode-debugger, I am now using     **contribEditorLineNumberMenu**, but when I download **vscode.proposed.contribEditorLineNumberMenu.d.ts** for using **editor/lineNumber/context**, the file is empty. Could you let me know when this file is update?

Thank you!

I tried using **editor/lineNumber/context** with empty file **vscode.proposed.contribEditorLineNumberMenu.d.ts** and debugger did not work well. I expect that I can add new command into line number context.